# How do I read this error message from IIS 7.5?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, encoding, character-encoding, restsharp

I am getting this error from the server when trying to use a REST web API, using RestSharp.

```
response    
"StatusCode: InternalServerError, 
Content-Type: text/plain; 
charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 52)" 
RestSharp.IRestResponse {RestSharp.RestResponse}

Content 
"\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\u0004\0��,.��KW(H,J�M-I-�R\bN��I-r�OI���\u0002\0�\u0005�w \0\0\0"  
string

RawBytes    {byte[52]}  byte[]
        [0] 31  byte
        [1] 139 byte
        [2] 8   byte
        [3] 0   byte
        [4] 0   byte
        [5] 0   byte
        [6] 0   byte
        [7] 0   byte
        [8] 4   byte
        [9] 0   byte
        [10]    243 byte
        [11]    205 byte
        [12]    44  byte
        [13]    46  byte
        [14]    206 byte
        [15]    204 byte
        [16]    75  byte
        [17]    87  byte
        [18]    40  byte
        [19]    72  byte
        [20]    44  byte
        [21]    74  byte
        [22]    204 byte
        [23]    77  byte
        [24]    45  byte
        [25]    73  byte
        [26]    45  byte
        [27]    178 byte
        [28]    82  byte
        [29]    8   byte
        [30]    78  byte
        [31]    205 byte
        [32]    201 byte
        [33]    73  byte
        [34]    45  byte
        [35]    114 byte
        [36]    206 byte
        [37]    79  byte
        [38]    73  byte
        [39]    213 byte
        [40]    227 byte
        [41]    229 byte
        [42]    2   byte
        [43]    0   byte
        [44]    167 byte
        [45]    5   byte
        [46]    231 byte
        [47]    119 byte
        [48]    32  byte
        [49]    0   byte
        [50]    0   byte
        [51]    0   byte
```

I believe that many of the programmers of the web API are Korean, so could it be possible that this error is meant to be in Korean?  If I could decode into Korean characters, then I can just put them through GoogleTranslate.

Answer (score 0):

you can decode each character by writing a small piece of code, ex

```
char c = "\u001f".toCharArray()[0];
```

So decode the string and try to get the error..

Comment: But some might be multi-byte characters.  Is there an online tool where I can paste that it, and it displays all the possible decodings?

Comment: try this online tool http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php, ex- I tried converting your value and it resulted into

Comment: **Error:Invalid or unexpected token**

Comment: Hi Sumit Jolly, thanks, but I tried the tool, and couldn't get the same result as you, what did you need to paste into that tool?

Comment: Hello, I simply copied the content and pasted in the tool I shared, "\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\u0004\0��,.��KW(H,J�M-I-�R\bN��I-r�OI���\u0002\0�\u0005�w \0\0\0". ** please try **

Comment: I think what we are seeing is an error message from the tool itself. (not the decoding of the string)  You can try by deleting part of the input or appending to it, and see that there is no effect.